# Sql subselect per foreign key

Tags: sql, oracle, subquery

I have a table like this:

*Person Table:*

```
Name    | Age | FK Adress 
Thomas  |  50 |    1      
Lisa    |  20 |    1      
Lisa    |  20 |    2      
Ramon   |  31 |    3      
Kata    |  56 |    4      
Thomas  |  50 |    5      
Robert  |  73 |    6      
Karl    |  78 |    7      
Edda    |  11 |    8      
Yogi    |  22 |    9
```

Now the user want have all addresses where thomas 50 AND lisa 20 both MUST be.
I want get back only FK 1.

My solution is the following (example code):

```
select fk 
from person 
where name = thomas and age = 50 
and fk in 
  (select fk from person where name = lisa and age = 20)
```

This works, but give it a better solution as subselect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yours will work, but an FK is usually a PK in another table. Maybe you can start from that table?

```
select pk 
from address a
where 
  exists (
    select 'x' from person p 
    where name = 'lisa' and age = 20 and p.fk = a.pk) and
  exists (
    select 'x' from person p 
    where name = 'thomas' and age = 50 and p.fk = a.pk)
```

Alternatively, you can count the matching names. This will make it easier to add names, although it might be slower.

```
select pk 
from address a
where 
  2 = -- the number of names that should match 
  (select count('x') 
   from person p 
   where 
     p.fk = a.pk and 
     ( (name = 'lisa' and age = 20) or
        name = 'thomas' and age = 50)
     )
```

Also, an inner join will work, as long as the combination of name, age and fk is unique, otherwise you'll get double results:

```
select a.pk 
from 
  address a
  inner join person l on l.fk = a.pk and l.name = 'lisa' and l.age = 20
  inner join person t on t.fk = a.pk and t.name = 'thomas' and l.age = 50
```

I don't know whether these will outperform your own query, but I think both are semantically more correct, if you will, and possably easier to understand and easier to expand.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but I don't understand where the address a table in your solution comes from.

Comment: It's an assumption that there is another table, since the field is an FK. An FK is a key from another table, so..  :)  If there is no such table, then your self join is a perfect solution (it's a good solution anyway, +1), but in that case, the term 'FK' would be very confusing. :)

Comment: AH yes, I see what you are going for now...start at the primary table and join on the FK.  That is a cleaner idea.  Heh, 3 alternatives is still only +1 not +3 ;)

Comment: I could split it in three different answers, but I think that's a little overkill.

Answer (score 2):

Self join?

```
Select a.fk
from person a inner join person b on a.fk = b.fk
where a.name = 'thomas' and a.age = 50 
and b.name = 'lisa' and b.age = 20
```

not sure if that'll out preform, but it should do decently well.